# access child DOM object from parent in dotted notation

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to select a child DOM object by treating it as data member of its parent DOM object?  Imagine I have this code:

```
<div id=div1>
   <div id=innerdiv1></div>
   <div id=innerdiv2></div>
</div>
<div id=div2>
   <div id=innerdiv1></div>
   <div id=innerdiv2></div>
</div>
```

This example won't work in real life because both pairs of child divs have the same id's (innerdiv1, innerdiv2), but that's exactly what bothers me about the "id" thing.
Is there some way in javascript to access a child element as a data member, something like `document.getElementById('div1.innerdiv1')`, which would return a different object from `document.getElementById('div2.innerdiv1')`.
I can't stand that each id has to be unique throughout the document.  It becomes a major issue when you have a lot of code and you accidentally use the same id twice. It makes for really nasty bugs that are difficult to squash.

Comment: HTML IDs must be unique. Period.

Comment: "It becomes a major issue when you have a lot of code and you accidentally use the same id twice. It makes for really nasty bugs that are difficult to squash." you're not helping your case :P

Comment: on a side note, your attribute values must be quoted.

Comment: what do you mean I'm not helping my case?  Do you never create web pages that have lots of code?

Comment: I don't think the downvote on this question is justified. First of all, the question is perfectly valid from a formal point of view. Second, there's a variety of scenarios where it's hard to keep track of ids: for example when you're using `cloneNode(true)`

Comment: @J-bob you are trying at least to avoid making invalid html right? And it just sometimes happens that you need to deal with something that is invalid? I think people just wanted to reinforce that it's a bad practice to have duplicate IDs. Not that it never happens.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 it's a valid question, I wouldn't down-vote it. But "I can't stand that each id has to be unique throughout the document" is not a question and is both irrelevant to the question and indicates poor practice.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Until you answered, everything I found on the web and in this forum suggested that ID's must be unique.  I was led astray and was simply voicing what everyone was telling me.  But since every major language supports repeated identifier names at different scopes I thought it was fair to ask.  I don't know why I was downvoted either, I thought my question was perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` in modern browsers. `document.getElementById` is pretty much obsolete.

```
document.querySelector('#div1 #innerdiv1')
```

Comment: Holy mackerel! It works!  Whoever said this was impossible doesn't know what they're talking about.  It worked in Firefox and Chrome, do you know if it works for the modern IE, Safari and Opera?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that all browsers can handle multiple occurences of the same id, as well as the above selector syntax. So I'd say yes it's possible.

Comment: Availability depends if you need to support IE 6 or 7. http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Answer (score 1):

The `document` object has a `getElementById` method, but the returned elements do not have this method, and it couldn't take a string that isn't exactly the id of an element [if that's what you want try a library, like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) or [Pumbaa80's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776730/459) of [document.querySelector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776730/459)].

In some browsers you can try:

```
document.getElementById('div1').getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

As a side note, try dropping these two html documents into [html5.validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu) or http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>t</title></head><body>
<div id=div1><div id=d1>one</div><div id=d2>two</div>three</div>
<div id=div2><div id=d1>four</div><div id=d2>five</div>six</div>
</body>
```

Now you can totally avoid using the same id twice by just using classes instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>t</title></head><body>
<div id=div1><div class=d1>one</div><div class=d2>two</div>three</div>
<div id=div2><div class=d1>four</div><div class=d2>five</div>six</div>
</body>
```

For the first one, you could use `document.querySelector('#div2 #d1')` or `$('#div2 #d1')`
but I don't think the result would be guaranteed across all browsers due to the fact that this *should* be equivalent to writing `document.querySelector('#d1')`  which you can see returns the first occurring id that matches, or `$('#d1')` which returns both id matching elements in an array.

And for the second one you could use `document.querySelector('#div2 .d1')` or `$('#div2 .d1')` or the other statements for very similar results, except that your html is valid this time. You don't even have to have css that defines `d1` and `d2` and if you used an attribute like `class="d1 mySubHeading"` and `class="d2 mySubHeading"` you could style both with `mySubHeading` and leave `d1` and `d2` there purely for selection via these methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes for the inner divs instead of ids, which do not need to be unique.